# What does "어정쩡" and "어버버" in EXO Tempo Lyrics

Tags: translation, lyrics

I was trying to translate EXO Tempo lyrics to english 1 by 1... then I encountered "어정쩡" and "어버버"... what do they mean?

This is the verse where the two words appeared:

```
밖으로 나갈 채비 미리 해 둬
Are you ready? (Look)
오늘은 내가 캐리 도시 나 사이의 케미 (Aw)
이미 나와 놓곤 뭐가 창피해 My boo (Ah)
어정쩡 어버버 할 필요 없다고 (Coming out)
[첸/세] 챙길 건 없으니 손잡아 My lady
[첸/세] 가는 길마다 Red carpet 또 렌웨이인걸
발걸음이 남달라 (Swish)
[첸/세] 지금 이 속도 맞춰 보자 Tempo aw
```

Thanks... :)

Answer (score 1):

> 어버버하다 : When someone speaks falteringly (더듬거리다), then we
>   have a difficulty in understanding. In my thought, 어버버 is more
>   serious state.

1) 그의 말은 어버버 하게 들린다. His talking sounds like 어버버.

2) 나는 당황하면 어버버하게 된다. When I am in an embarrassment,
then I talk like spiting sounds '어버버'.

> 어정쩡하다 : vague, uncertain, losing a role or a position

1) 두 사람 사이에 내 처지(=사정, state or situation)가 어정쩡하다
(=난처하다)

Between two, I can not take a suitable stance.

2) 오줌 쌌니 ? 걸음걸이가 어정쩡하네 Do you lose your pee ? What is
your walking ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer... (but sorry for the very late reply... )

Answer (score 1):

'어버버' is an onomatopoeia word(Describing a sound).
When someone encounter a frustrating things, he/she speaks some words weakly.
Anyway..like the word 'murmur' in english, '어버버' is an onomatopoeia word in korean.

And the '어정쩡' is a mimetic word.
Exact meaning is explained in HK Lee's answer.
* Originally, '어정쩡' describes someone's pose or a position of something.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... (but sorry for the very late reply... )